# Пассивный доход через программинг?

Tags: it-бизнес

В какой IT области сейчас актуальнее сделать себе источник пассивного дохода? Чтобы сделал — оно работает, почти не требуя внимания, и приносит какие-то деньги.

- написать приложение под iPhone;
- сделать очередную игру для ВКонтакта;
- перепродажа хостинга - размещение у себя сайтов клиентов;
- запустить собственный интернет-магазин по перепродаже чего-то;
- наклепать кучу сайтов и косить с контекста и всяких сап (фу..);
- соорудить некий нужный почти всем веб-сервис с бесплатным+платным планами;

Да, вопрос неконкретный, но, надеюсь, интересен многим.

P.S. Один из ответов приму, и возьму как руководство к действию.

**Принял:** ok, vk!

Comment: мой втнутренний альтруист подсказывает, даже требует, чтобы вы соорудили **некий нужный почти всем веб-сервис с бесплатным+платным планами**

Comment: Мой тоже. Но вопросу оно не соответствует. ^_^

Comment: Вопрос действительно крайне интересный и будоражит многие умы, но проблема состоит в том, что в любой перечисленной области потребуется постоянное вмешательство, чтобы поддерживать этот доход. Пассивный доход можно иметь с недвижимости - сдаешь, деньги капают, недвижимость никуда не девается, всегда на том же месте.
Или приобрести акции - они растут, деньги преумножаются - все довольны.
Что касается IT - нужно трудиться постоянно. НО, с помощью IT технологий, можно создать себе стартовый капитал, который позволит дойти до пассивного дохода.

Comment: если поразмыслить, вечного источника дохода нет. Есть _достаточно долгие_.
Вот, упомянутая недвижимость: квартира - лет 50, в среднем. Капремонт - раз в 10 лет. Соответственно, 10 лет оно приносит доход без вложений и затрат, если таковыми не считать поиск клиента.

Так же и в инете, только быстрее.

Comment: @zhenyab недвижимость тоже не 100% айс: вижу, как тут подрываются с тропического острова в серую столицу некоторые знакомые, когда соскакивает их нынешний арендатор. Ищут нового.

Comment: Не знаю как у вас, но у нас недвижимость - это хорошее вложение капиталла. Но в целом конечно согласен, ничто не вечно под Луной.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> написать приложение под iPhone

Вряд ли вы легко напишете такое приложение. Доход скорее всего будет меньше затрат.

> сделать очередную игру для ВКонтакта;

Ближе всего. Аудитория большая, нетребовательная. Вспоминается пример с коровой в фейсбуке.

> перепродажа хостинга - размещение у себя сайтов клиентов;

Заклинаю! Пользаки задолбают. Я гарантирую это.

> запустить собственный интернет-магазин по перепродаже чего-то;

Супер. А продавать кто будет? Само? Ну-ну.

> наклепать кучу сайтов и косить с контекста и всяких сап (фу..);

Гореть в аду больно...

> соорудить некий нужный почти всем веб-сервис с бесплатным+платным планами;

Сначала соорудить, потом раскрутить, потом поддерживать... Кверху пузом лежать не получится.

Comment: Аццкий критик) пусть лучше все по пунктам делает )))

Answer (score 9):

Что человек ни сделает, чтобы только ничего не делать.

Answer (score 9):

Ни одно из перечисленных занятий не принесет вам ощутимого пассивного дохода - ну если только он не станет активным, то есть вы не начнете в**бывать по >= 40 часов в неделю. Все перечисленные виды деятельностей уже пропаханы раз на 100 миллионами прогером/кодеров, так что найти среди этого нечто такое которое будет востребованным будет крайне сложно.

Нужна деятельность которая сейчас никому неинтересна, но вот в будущем сможет принести ощутимые дивиденты.

Тут безусловно есть риск, поскольку может запросто статься, что через N лет эта деятельность все равно не будет приносить никакого дохода, а может и наоборот? Ну кто мог представить в 2006-м году (всего 6 лет назад), что выстрелит Twitter? С другой стороны сколько погибло и кануло в лету других стартапов?

Говоря короче: **не надо делать то, что делают все остальные**. Ищите стартап, вполне возможно через 10-к стартапов авось чего и выстрелит.

Comment: `10-к` прочитал как `10k`, хотя...

Comment: оговорка прям по Фрейду :)

Comment: @Spectre +1, я тоже)

даже **10^к**

Answer (score 5):

Программирование чего либо, строго с целью заработка денег, скорее всего обречено на неудачу. В любом случае - ощутимого пассивного дохода вы не получите точно.

Хотя, если ваши цели не велики (в плане денег), то вы, конечно, можете вымучать ***какой-то*** проект. Если постараться и немного везения - он будет приносить некоторый доход. ( при таком подходу вообще не важно что именно делать ). Даже если он образуется, он, скорее всего, практически моментально испариться, т.к. вам, интересны именно деньги, вы не увидите целесообразности развития и поддержки.

По факту, намного лучше было-бы все это время тупо проработать ( банально, скорее всего, это принесло бы намного больше денег )

Вообще, сама ваша мысль "пассивного" дохода, на мой взгляд, уже говорит о том, что все, что вас интересует - это, непосредственно, деньги. При таких раскладах, вам лучше пробовать себя в чем-то другом ( я имею введу - с целью получения пассивного дохода ).

Вы будете готовы зарабатывать деньги самостоятельно тогда, когда у вас появиться, хотя-бы на ваш взгляд( сия вставка ИМХО, я считаю, что, если человек действительно в чем-то заинтересован и он не хоронит своей затеи и действительно в это верит, это, так или иначе, обязательно даст свои плоды ), интересная идея, либо, как минимум, вы будете сильно заинтересованы в разработке чего-либо ( даже если вы не особо верите в это, но вам это тупо интересно ).

Вернее будете готовы "подойти" к заработку ***НЕ*** пассивным доходом, ощутимый пассивный доход хоть и существует, но это настолько редкое явление, что я-бы не стал на него надеяться, я бы даже сказал что это миф. Да и то, что люди называют пассивным доходом, по факту не является абсолютно пассивным.

---

Конечно, не факт, что это самое "чего-либо" вообще когда-то будет приносить доход и, уж точно, далеко не сразу, но:

- если вам это, хотя-бы интересно, поверьте мне, для вас это не будет иметь такого большого значения. А если это была та самая идея, которую вы не бросили и не собираетесь бросать, то, опять таки, мое сугубо личное мнение, со временем, деньги придут к вам сами и, что самое главное, как я уже писал выше - это не будет иметь для вас высшего приоритета, скорее очень приятный бонус.
- Москва тоже не за день строилась. Не будет приносить денег первый проект, принесет другой.

---

К тому-же прелесть такого рода начинаний в том, что вы абсолютно ничем не рискуете, так что, резюмирую, я бы посоветовал следующее:

- выбирайте то, что вам больше нравиться, если вы будете работать с тем, что практически никак вам не интересно, вы не получите ни удовольствия, ни денег.
- если вам ничего не интересно, лучше вообще не браться, ищите другой путь, это, не при каких раскладах не для вас

PS: практически все вышеизложенное - сугубо мое личное мнение, не претендующее на абсолютную истину.

PPS: ИМХО, даже приложение под IOS и т.д., написанное строго для получения определенного дохода - не будет хорошо продаваться. Исключение составляют только те случаи, когда вы уверены в том, что вы нашли ту нишу, где вы могли-бы много заработать, но это, по сути, можно отнести к той самой идее, о которой я писал выше.

---

В любом случае удачи

Comment: для тех, кто ниасилил:

**Делайте то, что вам интересно!**

Comment: Беда в том, что мне **интересно** всё перечисленное! : )

Как в [этом][http://nopattern.tumblr.com/post/27908662328/tutorial] уроке.

Comment: Тогда пробуйте себя везде, как я уже писал - вы ничем не рискуете.

Comment: О, минус, привет @karmadro4 :D

Answer (score 4):

Все, чтоб вы ни сделали, не станет приносить вам доход без дальнейшего вмешательства, так как мир не стоит на месте: кто-то может сделать лучше вас, красивее и т. д.

*P.S. Не помню кто сказал: "Иногда надо очень сильно бежать, чтоб оставаться на месте".*

Comment: Да, Кэп! Пару часов в неделю, какой-то % от приносимого дохода — разумеется, надо отдавать в этот источник. Но не 40 часов, и не все фамильные брильянты спустить на это )

Comment: Тогда формулируйте точнее. :) Брильянты тоже могут приносить пассивный доход

Comment: Как мог: «оно работает, **почти** не требуя внимания»

Answer (score 2):

Вот любопытно, вы действительно умеете кодить под iOS, владеете API Вконтакте, можете ресселить хостинг и оказывать юзверям техподдержку, обладаете SEO и маркетинговыми навыками? Так тогда вам цены нет :)
Конкретно по теме: ИМХО проще всего сделать **классное** приложение для iOS, это действительно может приносить какое то время пассивный доход. Скорее всего незначительный и несоизмеримый с затратами, как уже говорилось выше

Comment: Лучше всего я умею под пальмой с кокосом валяться =)

Под iOS+Android на Lua в Corona SDK делал простенькие приложения ради "попробовать". Под vk API есть несколько работающих штук. С юзверями общаюсь, сайты поддерживаю. Будете смеяться, но работал несколько лет хэдом маркетинга в международной ко., но, признаюсь, в маркетинге я не спец : ) SEO - только в объёме общей эрудированности.

Comment: Цены нет, мне бы хоть отчасти сейчас обналичиться.. Вот прямо сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Пишите биржевого или покерного робота, вдруг случится чудо и ваш код сможет играть в плюс.

Comment: Если вы не в курсе, то я вам сообщу - любого рода онлайн (на самом деле, не только онлайн, но это оффтоп :)) азартные игры устроены так, что выигрывать, как минимум на протяжении долгого времени, невозможно :)

Comment: В курсе, поэтому и пишу про чудо.

Comment: @AlexWindHope откуда же тогда туча миллионеров, получивших доход, играя в покер

Comment: ну это вы утрируете, миллионерами становяться единицы профессионалов

Comment: Покер - игра интелекта, а не везения. Это вам не бандита за кой-что дергать.

Comment: @mikillskegg именно это я и имел в виду--професссионал способен свести долю везения [очень близко] к нулю

Comment: [ну-ну](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWmPCq-UJVU)

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов - вы думаете хоть кто-то из них играл в тот покер, о котором идет речь здесь? Если да - вперед, вот же вам идея на миллион :D

Comment: С++ Хедз-ап бот на OpenCv с подключенной базой рук, встроенным odds калькулятором, генетическим алгоритмом или нейронной сетью для самообучения спектру калирования на истории при игре с игроком с которым он уже играл и встроенной системы банкролл менеджмента на основе оптимальной фиксированной доли или формулы Келли определенно является сверхгенератором пассивного программистского дохода.

Comment: > Покер - игра интелекта, а не везения

Хех, а игра чего тогда шахматы? 

И вообще, этот тред уже привлек такое кол-во бреда, что хватило бы вырыть котлован.